# Why is shutdownNow() works before it is being called?

Tags: java

Could you please help me with understanding shutdownNow() method in Java.
I have a simple code: it starts 10 Threads in a loop and prints their names.
It has also shutdownNow() method, but as the for loop is being above shutdown() I thought that for loop should be finished and then shutdownNow() called.

As we can see, it doesn't work that way. I have  always the same result: half of the loop is done and then shutdownNow() called.
Why is it so?

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            final int localId = i;
            executor.submit(() -> doExpensiveOperation(localId));
        }
        executor.shutdownNow();



    }

    private static void doExpensiveOperation(int localId) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ", localId=" + localId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read the javadoc for [`shutdownNow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdown())? It explains the behaviour you're observing. Also, please explain which behaviour you were expecting, so that we can give you an alternative (if such an alternative exists).

Answer (score 1):

The expensive operation is executed asynchronously, that's the whole point of ExecutorService. So as soon as you submitted all tasks to the service, the calling method is continued, and the shutdownNow method is called.

If you want to run all method calls in the for loop synchronously, you can just remove the usage of ExecutorService and call the method directly.